# Cant boot old drive after adding new drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, sata

I have an HP EliteDesk 800 with a 500G drive on SATA-0. I added a 1TB drive on SATA-1. The 1TB drive came from a Window 8 machine where it was the primary drive. After the new drive was added the machine insists on booting the new 1TB drive. I can boot the old 500G drive using the boot menu but I cannot make it the default (not in the boot order list). I formatted the new drive but it still tries to boot (and now fails). What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to switch the disk connectors.

Comment: Doubtful the old W8 install will boot on different hardware.